# Jquery date field change function working in Chrome but not in Mozilla

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to get the date, month, the year from input date given by the user. but these function perfectly works in google chrome but they are not working in Mozilla firefox. But I need them in Mozilla also. Please could anyone help me.

```
$("#dob").change(function(){
    var birthday = $("#dob").val();
    var d=new Date(birthday.split("/").reverse().join("-"));
    var dd=d.getDate();
    var mm=d.getMonth()+1;
    var yy=d.getFullYear();
    var newdate=yy+"/"+mm+"/"+dd;

    alert(newdate);

    var datas = "birthdate=" + newdate;
    $.ajax({
        url: '/pages/verify',
        type: 'GET',
        data: datas,
        success: function(output){
            if(output.status == 0){
                information_alert("Sorry you are not eligible to access this site..");
            } else if(output.status == 1) {
                window.location = '/dashboard';
            }
        }
    });
});
```

I get this by using an alert

```
 NaN/NaN/NaN
```

Comment: Its working... Can you give the example data of '$("#dob").val();' ?

Comment: Can you please tell the format of $("#dob").val() or any example value

Comment: '02-08-2017' in `mm/dd/yyyy` format

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this...

you are using `mm/dd/yyyy` format as input and then reversing this with "-" results to `yyyy-dd-mm` which is invalid date format.

```js
var birthday = '02/22/2017';
var d = new Date(birthday.split("/")[2] + "-" + birthday.split("/")[0] + "-" + birthday.split("/")[1]);
var dd = d.getDate();
var mm = d.getMonth() + 1;
var yy = d.getFullYear();
var newdate = yy + "/" + mm + "/" + dd;
alert(newdate);
```

Answer (score 0):

According to your input in the comment, when reversed, the format changes to 'yyyy/dd/mm' (from 'mm/dd/yyyy'). But inside new Date() the accepted format is 'mm/dd/yyyy' (not 'yyyy/dd/mm').
So just remove the reverse() from your code like below:

```
var d=new Date(birthday.split("/").join("-"));
```

That's it I think.